# How to call functions of Child Object stored in parent type variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to store the instance of a Child class in a parent variable. When i try to use the parent variable to call the Child's functions, I am unable to do so. How can i use the Child functions ?

```
class Parent{
  public teach(){
   console.log("Parent teaching");
  }
}

class Child extends Parent{
  public learn(){
    console.log("Child Learning");
  }
}

Parent a = new Child();

a.learn(); //Does not exist in parent
```

Comment: `Parent` class does not have method learn, it's `Child` class method. You should use `Child a = new Child();`

Comment: @DamianPioś this question is regarding polymorphism. I should be able to save a child in a parent and call the child's function through parent variable.

Comment: no, polymorphism means that you can have variable of any type that extends some super class, and only methods defined in this super class are accessible, in your case you want to achieve sth opposite.

Comment: @DamianPioś you should do a bit research on this because it is possible to do this in C++ using <dynamic cast> which checks what the variable is point at and not the variables pointer type.

Comment: according to tags, question is about typescript, and i'm answering how it works in this language

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing called " Upcasting " in typescript.

```
Parent a = new Child();
a.learn(); //Does not exist in parent
```

will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent to call the child method, you could do something like

```
abstract class Parent {
  abstract learn();
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public learn(){
    console.log("Child Learning");
  }
}

const a: Parent = new Child();
a.learn(); // now exists
```

Comment: I did try this but still it will say that learn() does not exist in parent. I have found a way to solve this issue which is using TypeAssertion

Comment: @Ashim that's not true - I copied the exact same code, pasted it at Typescript Playground and it does print `Child Learning`

Answer (score 0):

After googling for a while,I finally found the answer.
As you know that in C++ we can use dynamic cast inorder to check the type during run time. However, this is not possible in javaScript. Hence, the right choice would be to use `"Type Assertion"`.

```
let b = a as Child;
b.learn();
```

Now, you can use b as what it should be which is a Child.

> If you want to learn more:
>
> https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: Type assertion is purely a Typescript type-change and pre-compiler check. The code that runs is a JS code, and the type-assertion does not _change_ the code that is compiled, meaning `a.learn()` and `(a as Child).learn()` is the _exact_ same JS code